# Navbar not aligning

Tags: html, css, alignment, navbar

I really need help on alignment of navbar in fixed header 
I want the text above the nav bar to be to the left of the nav bar in the menuTop and the navbar to be to the very right in menuTop

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g2Sr9/

HTML:

```
<div class="myMenuTop">
    <span class="myFont1">Company&trade;</span>
    <ul id="navmenu">
        <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">3</a><span class="darrow"></span>
            <ul class="sub1">
                <li><a href="#">3.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">3.2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">3.3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">4</a><span class="darrow"></span>
            <ul class="sub1">
                <li><a href="#">4.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">4.2</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">4.3</a><span class="rarrow"></span>
                    <ul class="sub2">
                        <li><a href="#">4.3.1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">4.3.2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">4.3.3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.myMenuTop {
    height:40px;
    width:100%;
    min-width:536px;
    background-color:#000;
    position:fixed
}

.myLogo {
    height:300px;
    width:100%;
    min-width:536px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
    border-top:1px solid #000;
    align:center;
    text-align:center
}

* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}

.img1 {
    height:211px;
    width:550px;
    min-width:500px
}

/* RULES FOR NAVIGATION MENU*/
/* ================================================ */
ul#navmenu,ul.sub1,ul.sub2 {
    list-style-type:none;
    font-size:9pt
}

ul#navmenu li {
    width:100px;
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    margin-right:4px
}

ul#navmenu a {
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
    width:100px;
    height:25px;
    line-height:25px;
    background-color:red;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    border-radius:5px
}

ul#navmenu .sub1 a {
    margin-top:5px
}

ul#navmenu .sub2 a {
    margin-left:10px
}

ul#navmenu li:hover > a {
    background-color:grey
}

ul#navmenu li:hover a:hover {
    background-color:#FA07AD
}

ul#navmenu ul.sub1 {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:26px;
    left:0
}

ul#navmenu ul.sub2 {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:101px
}

ul#navmenu li:hover .sub1 {
    display:block
}

ul#navmenu .sub1 li:hover .sub2 {
    display:block
}

.darrow {
    position:absolute;
    top:5px;
    right:4px;
    font-size:11pt
}

.rarrow {
    position:absolute;
    top:6px;
    right:4px;
    font-size:13pt
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to set the float element to be left for the left aligned content and right content to the right.

```
.myFont1{
    float: left;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#navmenu{
    float: right;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

really all you need is a `float: left` applied to .mylogo, and a `float: right` applied to #navmenu to accomplish exactly what you asked.

```
.mylogo {
    float: left;
}

#navmenu {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: How do I get the text company to be in the same row as the navbar?

Answer (score 0):

I have changed it please check and revert back, Please expand the result window a bit so that both can be accommodated in the bar.

```
Changed some css 

myMenuTop -> float:left; display:inline block;

navmenu  -> float:right
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/69Pew/)